# Layer text on top of linked image without using CSS relative positioning?

Tags: javascript, css

I wrote a [Booking Slots Calendar](http://www.planetphp.co.uk/php-booking-calendar/) for fun some time ago.  On the page is a live demo.
My aim is to layer text over a hyperlinked image within a table cell without using CSS positioning.  That's a bit of a mouthfull, let me explain...

Each green or orange block on the calendar indicates a bookable date, and each one is a  with the relevant coloured image, each hyperlinked to the relevant date.  Overlaying the day number on top of the image was not easy and the only cross browser solution I found was to add a span tag and position it relatively.  The problem with this is that the area under the number is non-clickable and it confuses people sometimes because they expect everything within the cell to be clickable.  Here is a sample  cell:

```
<td width='21' valign='top' class='days'>
    <a href='calendar.php?month=05&amp;year=2013&amp;day=06'>
    <img src='images/block_free.gif' title='This day is free' border='0' alt=''></a>
    <span>6</span>
</td>
```

Is there a better way to acomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td width='21' valign='top' class='days'>
    <a href='calendar.php?month=05&amp;year=2013&amp;day=06' class="green">6</a>
</td>

<style>
a.green { display: block; width: 64px; height: 50px; background: url( "images/block_free.gif" ) no-repeat; text-align: center; line-height: 49px; }
</style>
```

// Not entirely sure about the line-height value, test until you get a good value